# PHP Unserialize Javascript serialized string

Tags: javascript, php, serialization, deserialization

Good day,

I got a new script (for me it is) that allows you to create a draggable tree view.

The order of the tree structure can be changed and also stored.
I managed to send and fetch the updated structure.

However I have not yet succeeded in unserializing the string.
Before I am going to write my own logic to decode the array I would like to know if PHP knows some functionality by default to solve this issue?

**Example**

The String that I have :

```
spans-divs[0][id]=null&spans-divs[1][id]=null&spans-divs[1][children][0][id]=null&spans-divs[1][children][0][children][0][id]=null&spans-divs[2][id]=null&spans-divs[3][id]=null
```

The code that generates this string :

```
serialized[0].hash
```

I hope anyone could tell me what I have done wrong. OR IF this even a usable structure.

Thanks in advance

*Note*
The results are bing written by PHP to a file called test.txt

When I try to get the results I try it like this:

```
<?php
$cont   = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$Str    = parse_str($cont);
echo '->'.$Str.'<-';
?>
```

This produces : ><
Hence an empty string.

The following is a working solution:

```
<?php
$cont   = file_get_contents('test.txt');
parse_str($cont, $Str);
echo print_r($Str);
?>
```

(* the array that comes out of it is pretty useless actually *) but THANKS

Comment: Not 100% sure, but [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) might do the trick?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have already tried this.

Comment: You're using it wrong. https://3v4l.org/a9SkG or try accessing the variables using the names in the string. Just read the docs for how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
$arr = [];
$string = "spans-divs[0][id]=null&spans-divs[1][id]=null&spans-divs[1][children][0][id]=null&spans-divs[1][children][0][children][0][id]=null&spans-divs[2][id]=null&spans-divs[3][id]=null";
parse_str($string, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php